# Filter function returns an empty array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, filter

So when I call my handleRemove function here, if i return and console.log `el`, I get each one of my todos. However, if I return and console.log el[index], OR el[index].id, I get nothing but an empty array. I've looked into the docs of the Array.prototype.filter method but I don't understand what I am doing wrong here.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import TodoInput from './todo-input';
import TodoList from './TodoList';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      todos: [],
      inputValue: ''
    }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleRemove = this.handleRemove.bind(this);
  };

  handleChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      inputValue: e.target.value
    });
  }

  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const newTodo = {
      title: this.state.inputValue,
      id: Date.now(),
      done: false
    };
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      todos: [...prevState.todos, newTodo],
      inputValue: ''
    }));
  }

  handleRemove = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const newTodos = this.state.todos.filter((el, index) => el[index]);
    // this.setState((prevState) => ({
    //   todos: newTodos
    // }));
    console.log(newTodos);
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div>
          <TodoInput
          value={this.state.inputValue}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
          />
          <TodoList 
          todosArr={this.state.todos}
          onRemove={this.handleRemove}
          />
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

TodoList.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import TodoItem from './TodoItem';

class TodoList extends Component {
  render() {
    const mappedTodos = this.props.todosArr.map((todo, index) => 
      <TodoItem
      key={index}
      todoTitle={todo.title}
      handleRemove={this.props.onRemove}
      todoId={todo.id}
      />
    );

    return (
      mappedTodos
    );
  }
}

export default TodoList;
```

Comment: In `this.state.todos.filter((el, index) => el[index]);`, `index` is the position of `el` itself inside `this.state.todos`. Accessing `el[index]` doesn't make sense. You get an empty array because accessing `el[index]` likely returns `undefined`, i.e. a falsy value. `.filter` removes all elements for which the callback returns a falsy value. And you should be able to see that `el[index]` doesn't make sense if you look at the properties that `el` actually has (`title`, `id`, `done`). However, we cannot really help you if we don't know what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: What are you trying to accompish in the `filter` call? Looking at the code, it seems you may be confused about what `filter` does / how it works.

Comment: I am trying to use filter to return all of the todos which id's do not match the clicked todos id.

Comment: But when I return `el`, I get back the todos array. So how does accessing that index not access the elements in the array? That must be where im confused.

Comment: `el` is an element in the array. `index` is the index of that element in the array. `['a','b'].filter((el, index) => console.log(el, index))` will log `'a' 0` followed by `'b' 1`.

Comment: *"I am trying to use filter to return all of the todos which id's do not match the clicked todos id. But when I return el, I get back the todos array."* You shouldn't return `el`. You need to perform exactly the operation you just described: `this.state.todos.filter(todo => todo.id !== clickedToDoID)`

Answer (score 1):

Filter expects a true/false response, so you need to compare `el` to some kind of condition, like for example an id.

## Demo

https://repl.it/@AnonymousSB/SO53402083

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      todos: [
        { id: 123, value: 'Water the dog' },
        { id: 456, value: 'Rake the floor' }
      ]
    }
  }
  handleRemove(e, id) {
    const todos = this.state.todos.filter(todo => todo.id !== id)
    this.setState({ todos })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <section style={{width: 500}}>
        <ul>
          {this.state.todos.map(todo => {
            return <li onClick={(e) => this.handleRemove(e, todo.id)}>{todo.value}</li>
          })}
        </ul>
      </section>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: But when I return `el`, I get back the todos array. So how does accessing that index not access the elements in the array? That must be where im confused.

Comment: How are you getting the id of the clicked todo? Do you want to access the element's props? or pass it into the function? or save it to state and read it from there?

Comment: `index` in the filter function isn't doing anything for you. Filter expects the function you pass it to return true or false, and based on that, it will throw away or keep certain entries. Take a look at my updated code example.

Comment: im wanting to save it to props and access it there. I want to read all todos from state, then remove an element by clicking on the button in the DOM, I want it to remove the todo item from state, thus removing it from the DOM
PS: Sorry for the long respond times, I seriously appreciate your quickness

Comment: If you try my demo, that is exactly what it does. If you click on any list item, it will be removed from `this.state.todos`.

Comment: Well now it's telling me my this.props.todosArr.map() is not a function. When it was clearly mapping fine before. As I understand it, maps only work on arrays. Which in my TodoList, todosArr points to the todos array in my state. This is the only solution that has triggered this error though, so could it be something related to that? This is odd...

Comment: I have been messing with it and todo always returns the entire todos array, and id always points to an empty array, whether I call it by itself or call todo.id. Obviously it's cause our code is different, but I am still pretty new to this and I really want to understand it well. I don't understand why adding that index parameter doesn't allow me to read correctly. I'm going to add in my TodoList.js maybe that will shed some light.

Comment: What does your todo data look like? Is it an array of objects? Does each object have a unique identifier?

Comment: Yeah its an array of objects with {title:... id:... done:...}

Comment: Could you get your code working on Repl.it? That way I can better diagnose what's wrong. It's free to signup, and you just search for "React" and then you can upload your project, or copy/paste

Comment: Alright here it is. https://repl.it/@colegonzales1/HeftyJoyfulAbilities

Comment: AnonymousSB? I posted my replit

Comment: I'll take a look at it and post an update, I'm out of town for the weekend.

Comment: Oh yeah I see how to do it that way, but I'm trying to utilize the component aspect of react cause the app is gonna be way more complex than this. That's why I have a TodoList.js and all that.

Comment: So, you're assigning the `id` of the todo to the `id` attribute of the button, but in your `handleRemove` function, you're expecting `id` as an argument. What you need to do is access `e.target.id` inside `handleRemove` and use that to compare against `todo.id` in your filter. `const todos = this.state.todos.filter(todo => todo.id === e.target.id); this.setState({ todos });`

Comment: Ok now we are getting to the root of the problem, because this is what I tried the first time around myself and it just deletes all of the todos. If I do:
setState({ todos }), I get an empty array returned and nothing gets removed from state.todos.
However if I do
setState({todos: todos}), it removes all items from state.todos.

Comment: @ColeGonzales, you really need to get at least 20 reputation so we can do direct chat.

Comment: Few notes. The issue is that `e.target.id` is a string, and `todo.id` is a number, so you'll need to wrap it in `parseInt()` like so: `parseInt(e.target.id)`. Another is that you want to change the operator from `===` to `!==`. Once you do that, you should be golden. Also, if you supply just a variable to an object, it'll use the variable name as the key, and the value of the variable as the value, so if you didn't rename `newTodos` to `todos` like I did, then that code won't work.

Comment: Oh wow that's incredibly helpful man. I'm new to stackoverflow, I've always referenced it but didn't make my own until this problem stumped me pretty hard, like I said I'm still learning haha. But I'm going to try some of this out and experiment and hopefully learn a lot more from this. I really really appreciate the hell out of you being so helpful!